# OSX 10.10.5 Kernel Panic with no Log of Crash

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, kernel-panic

I've been having an issue recently with a MacBook Pro 13'. It seems to randomly crash to a grey error screen, stating "Your computer restarted because of a problem. Press a key or wait a few seconds to continue starting up." This is happening randomly; I cannot pinpoint it to any specific software or sequence of actions. Sometimes artifacts and vertical black bars will appear on the screen before the shutdown.

Originally the laptop was on 10.10.3, and I know that version had many issues with kernel panics, so I updated to 10.10.5. They are less frequent, but do still occur, and I cannot locate any log files from either the console or from the system report in "About This Mac".

I cannot for the life of me figure this one out, and I'm really hoping it isn't a hardware issue, although from what I've researched so far, it could be bad RAM. Where could I locate logs of these errors (if they exist), and are there any known solutions? Would an update to El Capitan fix this?